# DisplayLink driver not detecting monitors in 21.10

Tags: displaylink, 21.10

I know it is very new but I upgraded to 21.10 this weekend. After the update I downloaded the latest DisplayLink driver from here:

https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu

However after the install and a reboot, it is not detecting my extra monitors. It says on the page that the driver can be modified for other distributions, but I am not clear on what I would need to do to make this work in 21.10.

https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/679060

can anyone give me any pointers or help me understand this.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: @see https://blog.kamens.us/2021/10/15/displaylink-now-working-for-some-hardware-for-ubuntu-21-04-21-10-nvidia-is-a-problem/